# Possible to "Buy All" Products on a Page or Purchase a Group?

Tags: expresso-store, subscriptions

We're looking into adding a "Buy All" button for a Charity / Auction site and the owner would like to have a buy all button that would add all items (each having a stock of 1) to the cart for purchase.

Second Question: Is it possible to visibly show when a product has been added to the cart? The reason being is that the items for sale will be in a grid side by side and the owner would like a way for people to know which items they have added to the cart by visibly altering a div tag (or something similar) once the item is residing in the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy All button:

Yes it is possible to add all items to the cart with a single button you would need to use the `{exp:store:product_form}` tag pair wrapped around your channel entries tag or Matrix/Grid or Relationship/Playa tag pair. Full documentation of the product_form tag can be found [here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_form_tag.html).

```
{exp:store:product_form}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="products" dynamic="no" limit="5"}
      {exp:store:product disable_form="yes" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
          <!-- add to cart form / product details -->
    {exp:store:product}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:store:product_form}
```

In cart:

You would want to use the `{qty_in_cart}` tag in the `{exp:store:product}` tag. Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="{if qty_in_cart}inCart{/if}">
```

Full documentation for this can be found [here](https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/product_tag.html#qty_in_cart)